# How fill the array with distinct values and with condition based on property of objects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

I have an array of question objects and I want to pick questions from that array randomly and distinctly until sum of every question score property meets the score that I specified for exam score.

I mean every student will have random and distinct exam questions then sum of question scores is equal to exam score.

assume:

```
let questions=[
{ ..., title:"question 1", score:0.75},
{ ..., title:"question 2", score:0.25},
{ ..., title:"question 3", score:1.5},
{ ..., title:"question 4", score:3},
{ ..., title:"question 5", score:0.75},
]
```

Now, if our exam score is 4.5, students should have:
Student #1

```
let pickedQuestions=[
{ ..., title:"question 3", score:1.5},
{ ..., title:"question 4", score:3},
]
```

Student #2

```
let pickedQuestions=[
{ ..., title:"question 1", score:0.75},
{ ..., title:"question 4", score:3},
{ ..., title:"question 5", score:0.75},
]
```

How it's possible?

it's my trying: (if sum of scores couldn't meet the exam score, it turns to infinite loop)

```
            let total = 0;
            let countTMP = 0;
            while (
              total != lenghtofQuestions
            ) {

              let randomIndex = Math.floor(
                Math.random() * questions.length
              );

                if (
                  total + parseFloat(questions[randomIndex].score) >
                  lenghtofQuestions
                ) {
                  if (pickedQuestions.length == 0) {
                    continue;
                  } else if (pickedQuestions.length > 0) {
                    pickedQuestions.pop();
                    total -= countTMP;
                    continue;
                  }
                }
              pickedQuestions.push({
                idQuestion: questions[randomIndex].id,
                title: questions[randomIndex].title,
                image: questions[randomIndex].image,
                score: questions[randomIndex].score
              });
               
              countTMP = questions[randomIndex].score;
              total += parseFloat(questions[randomIndex].score);
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```js
const allQuestions = [
  { title: 'question 1', score: 0.75 },
  { title: 'question 2', score: 0.25 },
  { title: 'question 3', score: 1.50 },
  { title: 'question 4', score: 3.00 },
  { title: 'question 5', score: 0.75 },
];

const EPSILON = .001

function generateQuiz (totalScore, questions = allQuestions, quiz = []) {
  questions = shuffle(questions)

  let nextQuiz, remaining, delta

  for (const next of questions) {
    delta = totalScore - next.score
    if (delta < -EPSILON) { continue }

    nextQuiz = [...quiz, next]
    if (delta <= EPSILON) { return nextQuiz }

    remaining = without(questions, next)
    if (!remaining.length) { continue }

    nextQuiz = generateQuiz(delta, remaining, nextQuiz)
    if (nextQuiz) { return shuffle(nextQuiz) }
  }

  return null
}

function shuffle (arr) {
  return [...arr].sort(() => Math.random() - .5)
}

function without (arr, item) {
  return arr.filter(i => i !== item)
}
```

**Update:** If you want to generate distinct quizzes for **each individual**, I'd recommend you to generate the tree of possible quizzes, then randomly choose N feasible quizzes.

Comment: Thanks so much!! how could I calculate number of possible quizzes?

Comment: you're welcome. after generating the tree of possible quizzes, you can take number of path permutations as total number of possible quizzes, if you dont care about order of quesitons.

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this. If the student is unable to score the desired exam score you should break out of it.

```
 let total = 0;
            let countTMP = 0;
            while (
              total != lenghtofQuestions
            ) {

              let randomIndex = Math.floor(
                Math.random() * questions.length
              );

                if (
                  total + parseFloat(questions[randomIndex].score) >
                  lenghtofQuestions
                ) {
                  if (pickedQuestions.length == 0) {
                    continue;
                  } else if (pickedQuestions.length > 0) {
                    pickedQuestions.pop();
                    total -= countTMP;
                    continue;
                  }
                }
              pickedQuestions.push({
                idQuestion: questions[randomIndex].id,
                title: questions[randomIndex].title,
                image: questions[randomIndex].image,
                score: questions[randomIndex].score
              });
               
              countTMP = questions[randomIndex].score;
              total += parseFloat(questions[randomIndex].score);

             if (total < 4.5) break;
            }
          }
```